# trouble with express.index sending a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I'm using express to do a very simple page. My `index.js` looks like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render(
    'index', 
        { 
            title: 'Expressssss',
            Tin: varTin,
            Tout : varTout,
            Hin : varHin,
            Tout_array : { 'date': 'Thu Mar 07 2013 22:00:04 GMT+0100 (CET)', 'value': '10062' }
        }
    );
};
```

On the file `index.ejs` I can use the values using for example `<%= Tin %>`... This works very well....

The problem is that `data = <%= Tout_array %>;` doesn't seem to work well. Using chromes console, it get an error on this line. The html code after parsing looks like this:

```
data = [object Object];
```

and the error at this point is

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

what am I doing wrong? why parsing any other variale works pretty good, but not this nested json structure? I'm using this, because I want to send a bigger array.

Thans

Comment: could we see the index.ejs file?

Comment: Without any other guidance, JavaScript `Object`s [`toString()`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2) to what you got -- `[object Object]`. If you want anything more useful, you have to be explicit in what format you want. For JSON, that's `JSON.stringify()`, as already suggested by others.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks for the idea. I encounter now 2 problems. First, JSON.stringify retirns a string with `"`-qhotes, which don't work... second, I need to add an extra quote to the array, `'[{},{}]‘` instad of `[{},{}]`.... So I need to convert from `[{"date":},{}]` to `'[{\'date\'},{}]‘`. somehow weird is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to generate client-side Javascript from an EJS template, I think you want this:

```
data = <%- JSON.stringify(Tout_array) %>;
```

Comment: THANKS!!! the `<%-` did the trick. Fist, I thought it was a typo, but it really made a difference. (Note, it is **not** the same as `<%=`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= JSON.stringify(Tout_array) %>
```